# How to visualize a percentage metric in Grafana using Elasticsearch data source?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents in Elasticsearch like the following,

```
POST test_results/_doc
{
   "name": "Adam",
   "passed": true,
   "timestamp": 1600161457008
}

POST test_results/_doc
{
   "name": "Thomas",
   "passed": true,
   "timestamp": 1600161457008
}

POST test_results/_doc
{
   "name": "Harry",
   "passed": false,
   "timestamp": 1600161457008
}

POST test_results/_doc
{
   "name": "Bob",
   "passed": true,
   "timestamp": 1600161457008
}
```

**I want to visualize the percentage of students who passed the exam in a given time duration**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the **Elasticsearch Bucket Script Aggregation**, the configuration in Grafana is shown below. Make sure to hide the count metrics and show only the percentage metric,

[image]

Comment: Recent versions of Grafana (at least v9) no longer allow you to select a boolean field in the field dropdown when *Sum* is selected, but you can work around that by not selecting any field and just using the script under Options. For accessing the boolean field you could use `doc['my_boolean_field']`.